# coffeescript syntax {var}?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Very simply I am seeing the following syntax using coffeescript in node, that I never saw using coffeescript in the browser.

```
  {foo} = app.locals.foo
```

I headed over to js2coffee to see what this does, but it appears to be identical in js output to

```
  foo = app.locals.foo
```

So what is going on here? What does the `{}` syntax mean in this context? Why would you use it?

Comment: If I put `{foo} = app.locals.foo` in js2coffee it says JS output is `var foo; foo = app.locals.foo.foo;`

Comment: @Juhana: Looking at something like [`{a,b} = c`](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%7Ba%2C%20b%7D%20%3D%20c) might be a little more enlightening.

Comment: @muistooshort I was just commenting on the *"it appears to be identical in js output to ..."* because for me it doesn't appear to be identical.

Comment: @Juhana: I see, too many `foo`s confusing everyone :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring):

> **Destructuring Assignment**
>
> To make extracting values from complex arrays and objects more convenient, CoffeeScript implements ECMAScript Harmony's proposed destructuring assignment syntax. When you assign an array or object literal to a value, CoffeeScript breaks up and matches both sides against each other, assigning the values on the right to the variables on the left.
>   [...]
>   Destructuring assignment can be used with any depth of array and object nesting, to help pull out deeply nested properties.

The relevant example is this one:

```
futurists =
  sculptor: "Umberto Boccioni"
  painter:  "Vladimir Burliuk"
  poet:
    name:   "F.T. Marinetti"
    address: [
      "Via Roma 42R"
      "Bellagio, Italy 22021"
    ]

{poet: {name, address: [street, city]}} = futurists
```

That is short hand for this:

```
name   = futurists.poet.name
street = futurists.poet.address[0]
city   = futurists.poet.address[1]
```

and you can see it in action [over here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:futurists%20%3D%0A%20%20sculptor%3A%20%22Umberto%20Boccioni%22%0A%20%20painter%3A%20%20%22Vladimir%20Burliuk%22%0A%20%20poet%3A%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%20%20%22F.T.%20Marinetti%22%0A%20%20%20%20address%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Via%20Roma%2042R%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Bellagio%2C%20Italy%2022021%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%7Bpoet%3A%20%7Bname%2C%20address%3A%20%5Bstreet%2C%20city%5D%7D%7D%20%3D%20futurists%0A%0Aconsole.log(name%2C%20street%2C%20city)).

Basically, the object form of destructured assignment allows you to unpack objects in a somewhat natural way. Perhaps a simpler example would help:

```
o =
    a: 'b'
    c: 'd'
    e: 'f'

{a, e} = o
```

That's shorthand for:

```
a = o.a
e = o.e
```

And another [demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:o%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20'b'%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20'd'%0A%20%20%20%20e%3A%20'f'%0A%0A%7Ba%2C%20e%7D%20%3D%20o%0Aconsole.log(a%2C%20e)).

You can think of the left hand side of a destructured assignment as a pattern that is used to unpack the right hand side.

Comment: This is a very nice and through answer. But I still don't understand why I would use `{foo}` instead of just `foo`, when they compile to the same thing in js.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: But, as Juhuna noted, `foo = app.locals.foo` and `{foo} = app.locals.foo` don't compile to the same thing. `a = b` compiles to `a = b` but `{a} = b` is `a = b.a`.