# What does "{createServer} = require 'connect'" mean in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

In this file : https://github.com/josh/nack/blob/master/src/server.coffee

The code is :

```
{createServer} = require 'connect'
{createPool}   = require './pool'
```

I want to know what is the return value with `require 'connect'`

and what does `{}` mean in `{createServer}`

Comment: Also see [coffeescript syntax {var}?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15395106/479863).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the {} is CoffeeScripts destructuring assignment.

```
//file connect.js 
...
module.exports = {
   createServer: function(){...},
   someOtherExport: function() {...},
   somethingDifferentAgain: function() {...}
};
```

Then in your module you can do your importing of only createServer

```
{createServer} = require "connect"
```

Or you could import all symbols defined in the connect module

```
{createServer,
 someOtherExport,
 SomethingDifferentAgain } = require "connect"
```

If you want know what is exported from connect you should simply iterate over it

```
theModule = require 'connect'
for key, value of theModule
    console.log "#{key}: - #{value}"
```